# Download file from URL with parameters and authentication required

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest, webclient, httpwebresponse

I have a recurrent task in my job that follow this steps:

1. Access my company website;
2. Sign-in;
3. Make a search;
4. Download a KMZ file from the search result page.

I do it every week and need to download more then 100 files per time, do you know?

I have a list with all result I need, so I created an application in C# to automate this process, but when the file is downloaded it is not the correct type (KMZ) and its content is the login page source code. It happens because I don't have the correct file name, it is loaded by some parameters in URL like https://mycompanywebsite.org/files/fileViewServlet?Parameter1=abx&Parameter2=xyz&Parameter3=123

That's what I did.

```
//Download the file for the returned list
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        //client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        String credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("myusernae" + ":" + "mypassword"));
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = $"Basic {credentials}";

        try
        {
            //Download the KMZ
            client.Proxy = null;
            client.QueryString.Add("parameter1", "value");
            client.QueryString.Add("parameter2", "value");
            client.QueryString.Add("parameter3", "value");
            outputFileName = "File_Name_" + row.Cells["FieldTitle"].Value.ToString() + ".kmz";
            client.DownloadFile("https://mycompanywebsite.org/files/fileViewServlet?", strTargetFolder + nomeArquivoEstaca);

    
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the authentication didn't fail? Is basic auth the actual authentication method for that site? As a note, since you're using `QueryParameters`, the final `?` in the URI shouldn't be there. Also, you should use a [NameValueCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection) and add your parameters to it. Since you're trying to download more files from the same address, you could use the [WebClient.BaseAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.baseaddress) feature.

Comment: I think the authentication is ok. The problema is downloaded file. As I said it is not the correct file. Doing that manually after I signed-in to the site and search what I need, the result page brings me back an ID Number. This number is used in link to download the file I need. It looks like this: https://cdol.lds.org/cdol/servlet/fileViewServlet?unitPdf.mapDefId=5&unitPdf.extraIndex=&unitPdf.orgExtId=12547 (ID Number). What I need is to save the file resulted from this URL in pre-defined folder on my computer. Can you help to edit my code to fit you suggestion?

Comment: This is not what you wrote: *the file (...) is not correct (...) its content is the login page source code*. Do you get back the LogIn page, or the page that contains the `ID` you mentioned? If it's the LogIn page, the authentication failed. If it's the page with this `ID`, extract the information and build the Query with it.

Comment: So, I can authenticate using webbrowser control, because this I think the authentication is ok, but here we are using WebClient maybe is not authenticating. When I click in that link (manually) a KMZ file is download, but in my application what is downloaded is the source code of the login page renamed as KMZ, not the file I need, do you know?

Comment: A WebBrowser is not `WebClient`. The fact that you can authenticate with a WebBrowser has nothing to do with the result you get using `WebClient`. The page you linked is using Web Form authentication. You are trying to LogIn using `basic` authentication. The two methods are completely incompatible. Search SO/Google for `HttpClient Web Form Authentication`.

Comment: Sorry friend, I did search, but I didn't find anything easy to understand :-(. Do you have some sample working code that I can update for my need. Is it possible to you help to do it? Sorry for my bad english, I'm from Brazil and have no large experience in development. Sorry.